# How to put column length or not null constraints with mix phx.gen.html

Tags: phoenix-framework

I would like to put length on DB columns with `mix phx.gen.html`.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found I should not put length, when I use `phx.gen.html`.
I should put length on migration file which is in `priv/repo/migrations`.

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsers do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :name, :string, size: 20, null: false
      add :email, :string, size: 120, null: false

      timestamps()
    end
  end
end
```